# WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR after changing nothing in my PC

Tags: bsod

from a certain time I have problems with BSOD's, only when playing games. In my targeted game, I have diffrent Renderers to set - Beta Vulkan and DirectX. On Beta Vulkan I had problems, so set it to default (DirectX) and problem was fixed for short time - got BSOD's again.

Ran OCCT both CPU test's, no problem.
Ran OCCT 3D test, and I got black screen and my PC got reset'ed.

Dirty updated GPU Drivers, didnt fixed it.
Now I reinstalling drivers (DDU and clean install).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dRDX6CE5qUQhADcMbBaDRY_gi0lPUvmm/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UT2pRmQ4C4DjFSwerMQTMmDgFYdJ9tDv/view

Can Somebody analyze those BSOD's file? I used WINDBG, Im not expirienced so I understand literally nothing.

Win10 x64 Pro,
rx580 armour,
ryzen 1600,
b350 tomahawk

**Reinstalled GPU drivers, and problem in OCCT got fixed. Now will check it in game.**

Answer (score 0):

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR is a hardware error and shut down is to protect your computer.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4028662/windows-how-to-fix-wheauncorrectableerror

> If you see the text “WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR,” it means that a
> hardware error has occurred.

Update your drivers (You said you did this), but let's be sure all drivers are updated.

Get the Hardware Test application for your computer and test the complete hardware setup. Make sure this includes memory. You might also consider properly re-seating the CPU and GPU chips.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, that's interesting, because I change nothing inside my PC, so 
theoretically it should not happend. Reinstalled GPU drivers, and problem in OCCT got fixed. Now will check it in game.

Comment: @CospriMalice "theoretically it should not happen[e]d".  Let me punch a hole in that theory.  Sometimes the connectors between RAM chips and motherboards results in "oxidization".  Simply removing the RAM chips, seeing if the connectors look clean, and re-inserting can cause perfectly working RAM chips to work better again in a perfectly working motherboard.  (The parts work well after this "re-seating", and would also work well with other RAM chips / another motherboard -- they are working parts.)  So things can break overnight "on their own".